# remove repeated rows while self join in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to remove repeated values from rows based on joins on same table but can't remove one value in one column in table1 mapped to same column in table2.

Table:
Note: not restricted to only one date in table, there can be many with multiple sid

```
date    | sid | comp | disc
-----------------------
23 june | 1  | az  | 20
23 june | 1  | ph  | 22
23 june | 1  | mg  | 10
23 june | 2  | mg  | 8
23 june | 3  | ph  | 15
23 june | 3  | az  | 11
------------------------
```

ON SELF JOINING

```
select t1.*, t2.comp as comp1, t2.disc as disc1
from table as t1
left join table as t2 on t1.date = t2.date and t1.sid = t2.sid and t1.comp <> t2.comp
```

```
Output from above query:

date    | sid | comp | disc | comp1 | disc1
-------------------------------------------
23 june | 1  | az  | 20     | ph    | 22
23 june | 1  | az  | 20     | mg    | 10
23 june | 1  | ph  | 22     | az    | 20
23 june | 1  | ph  | 20     | mg    | 10
23 june | 1  | mg  | 10     | mg    | 10
23 june | 2  | mg  | 10     | null  | null
23 june | 3  | ph  | 10     | az    | 11
23 june | 3  | az  | 11     | ph    | 10
```

Expected result: (Here I am trying to fetch combination of comp & comp1 where for each sid & date, distinct comp values mapped with mg only & if sid has only mg or non-mg values then null in comp1)
Note: No repeated rows when comp mapped to comp1

```
date    | sid | comp | disc | comp1 | disc1
-------------------------------------------
23 june | 1  | az  | 20     | mg    | 10
23 june | 1  | ph  | 20     | mg    | 10
23 june | 2  | mg  | 10     | null  | null
23 june | 3  | ph  | 10     | null  | null
23 june | 3  | az  | 11     | null  | null
```

Comment: Where are you getting  [comp ph, disc 20] & [comp mg, disc 10], & [comp ph, disc 10] in your expected output? I don't think its very clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: i don't get it, what are you asking? is these values missing from expected output? But i can see in 2nd row of expected result.

Comment: I misread the question, so have deleted my answer.

Comment: I ran your self join query based on your first table and it does not match up with the numbers you provided in your first output. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mkz9g7SB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l33m9gLZ)

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT t1.*, t2.comp as comp1, t2.disc as disc1, SUM(1) OVER(PARTITION BY date,sid,comp) AS cnt
FROM `table` t1
LEFT JOIN `table` t2 ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.sid = t2.sid AND t1.comp <> t2.comp 
)

SELECT 
  date, sid, comp, disc, 
  CASE WHEN comp1 <> 'mg' THEN NULL ELSE comp1 END AS comp1, 
  CASE WHEN comp1 <> 'mg' THEN NULL ELSE disc1 END AS disc1
FROM cte
WHERE
 (CASE WHEN comp <> 'mg' OR comp1 IS NULL THEN cnt END) = 1
 OR 
 (CASE WHEN comp <> 'mg' AND comp1 = 'mg' THEN cnt END) >= 2
```

Comment: what coalesce is actually doing here? i thought it is for replacing null values though there are no null values in repeated cases. can you pls explain?

Comment: First, you want to include records with ```t2.comp IS NULL``` because those are the ones where "sid has only mg or non-mg values". Second, you want to include records with ```t2.comp = 'mg'``` because those are the sids with "distinct comp values mapped with mg only". The use of ```COALESCE``` here is the same as ```WHERE t2.comp IS NULL OR t2.comp ='mg'```

Comment: i think this will not include cases where if i add `23 june | 3  | az  | 11` at last, this will totally remove last 2 records though i want wrt to each of these record comp1 as null

Comment: edited the data to include this scenerio.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include that scenario. See if that works for you.

Comment: summing of records will not work for cases where we records for each date & sid, comp only contains 2 records with one having `mg`.
eg. if we remove first row from sample data, this will return only null for comp1

Look here : https://dbfiddle.uk/aOpXKPJA

Comment: @loving_guy Thanks for pointing out. See updated answer.